# When an index is deleted, is it totally flushed from elasticsearch or it doesn't display only in kibana?

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana

After deleting `movie_indexer` index using the following command:

`curl -XDELETE "http://localhost:9200/movie_indexer/"`

does it get completely removed from elasticsearch or are there some traces of it available. 
If it's completely removed then why does logstash not read the same log file that the deleted index read?

Answer (score 1):

Found these links useful : "Deleting a document doesn’t immediately remove the document from disk; it just marks it as deleted. ES will clean up deleted documents in the background as you continue to index more data."

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/delete-doc.html

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/retiring-data.html

Answer (score 0):

The command you're issuing is against elasticsearch, so the delete happens there.

As for your second question, note that elasticsearch doesn't read log files.  Some other process (perhaps logstash, logstash-forwarder, filebeat, beaver, etc) was reading the file and sending the data along.  If you wanted the logs to be re-read, you'd need to configure those programs to do so.

Once logstash ships the logs to elasticsearch, it marks the data as sent and would have no idea that you've deleted the data from elasticsearch and want it to resent the logs.

Logstash stores the information on what it has sent in a "sincedb" file (it might be ".sincedb" and a suffix).  You could stop logstash, edit the file to remove information about the logfile, and restart logstash.

Comment: Yeah sorry it's logstash that reads the log files. Edited my question. Configuring the programs as in? could you explain a bit more? Thanks :)

Comment: Where is the sincedb found? i couldn't find it in logstash folder.

Comment: Try: find / -name ".sincedb*"